# How can I download address data and convert to postgresql database from Open Street Maps?

Tags: leaflet, geolocation, openstreetmap, nominatim

I tried downloading it via https://download.geofabrik.de/ and converted it using osm2pgsql to a postgresql database. However, the postgresql database is very weird looking. There is no longitude, latitude and generally most of the columns that DO exist are filled with "null". I'm unsure if I did something wrong when i converted it but something that I can see is the Polygon of some places and that looks correct if I double check with nominatim.

[This is more of what I'd like in my database.](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Baakenallee&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1) Things like coordinates and the address. I have none of that when I download it through geofabrik. I most definitely don't have a good understanding of how it works yet but if someone can help me out and tell me how I can get a database with the osm data I'd be thankful!

If there is anything else that you noticed could've gone wrong please tell me

Comment: The second link is from a Nominatim instance. Maybe you want to [install Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/)?